# How to skew normalization using a logarithmic scale?

Tags: javascript, normalization

I'm working on a program that reads data from a graph and plays the values at a certain frequency that has been normalized to show the variance between data points.

In testing I found that an "acceptable" sound range lies between 200 and ~3800 for frequency ranges that aren't too high or too low to be of use. This means that I need all of the data to be converted into that range of numbers. Here is a solution to that given those guidelines.

```
function normalize(enteredValue, minEntry, maxEntry, normalizedMin, normalizedMax) {

var mx = (enteredValue-minEntry)/(maxEntry-minEntry);
var preshiftNormalized = mx*(normalizedMax-normalizedMin);
var shiftedNormalized = preshiftNormalized + normalizedMin;

return shiftedNormalized;

}
```

This works, but it poses a small problem with certain cases. If a user has a very small value and a very large value in the same data set.

Simple Example: $1 profits for company A and $1 billion for company B there won't be an issue IF company C and D  etc... have profits that are extremely far away from the edge cases. However, let's say company C has a profit of $50 million. This is significantly more than $1  and far less than $1 billion and won't be too much of an issue. However, if D has a profit of $20 thousand then we might  have a problem.

**The numbers after normalization would be this (using 3800 as a max and 200 as a min):**

1 = 200.0000036

20 thousand = 200.072

50 million = 380

1 billion = 3800

Here we can see the obvious problem. IF we use the function above to normalize the sound into the desired frequency range, then a large data set with a huge variance in data could skew perception of what is being represented on the graph. Because of how normalization squeezes larger data into a smaller range of numbers, this becomes a problem only when the largest and smallest numbers are very far apart.

**Two potential solutions:**

- Set a maximum number that users can have in the data set. This is an easy fix, but it would limit the capabilities of the program when
  it comes to automatically parsing data from csv files because
  anything over the cap would simply play the highest frequency.
- The second solution is complicated and I'm not sure how to do it yet, which is what I'm hoping to gleam from you or someone to point
  me in the right direction. I think using some sort of logarithmic
  scaling to make larger data less significant would be a good
  solution. What I mean by this is something like this graph here:

[image]

Excuse my poor paint drawing skills, but you can see what I mean. As numbers get larger they get less and less significant. It's not how numbers work in relation to one another, but I think human perception of large numbers is already vague so it would be better to have larger numbers sound closer together than smaller numbers. (Such as 1 and 20,000).

What do you think?

Edit:
I think one of the comments mentioning taking log base 10 of the number is on the right track, however it wouldn't work for smaller data points because numbers would be too close together. IE Log 1 is 1 and log 10 is 2. 1 and 2 are so close together that you wouldn't hear a difference.

Comment: I'm not too good with expressing my ideas in terms of math, but how about instead of 'normal' normalization you would take a log base 10 instead. So that 1 would be 1, 10 would be 2, 100 would be 3, and so on? I think this would reduce the numbers even more.

Comment: The problem with that is that I do need to have a difference large enough for users to tell when a number is higher than the next one. A frequency change from 1 to 2 wouldn't register to most peoples ears. Taking log base 10 is part of a solution, but not the whole one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function normalize(enteredValue, minEntry, maxEntry, normalizedMin, normalizedMax) {

var mx = (Math.log((enteredValue-minEntry))/(Math.log(maxEntry-minEntry)));
var preshiftNormalized = mx*(normalizedMax-normalizedMin);
var shiftedNormalized = preshiftNormalized + normalizedMin;

return shiftedNormalized;

}
```

This should even out the distribution.

With the same parameters you gave, here are the new values:

1: 200

20 thousand: 1920.4119982655923

50 million: 3279.588001734408

1 billion = 3800.

This is using log10. For more or less logarithmic effect, use different bases, such as log2, or log16.

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post. I think this is a partial solution, but it will cause issues for smaller numbers.

Comment: 10 and 1 out of 1 billion are so close that the user should not hear a difference. Unless you are looking for something else? If you need finer resolution, use a smaller max input.

Comment: So the problem is that I don't know what data the user will be looking at. So it needs to be relative to what they need. I still would want them to hear a shift (Extremely slight, but still there) if the data went from 1 to 10. and then an extreme shift from 10 to 20,000

Comment: Can you program a way to get the data max from the user? For example, look at the maximum value of the graph, and put it into the function as `maxEntry`. This will allow fine resolution. If you really need fine resolution at low inputs with inputs up to 1 billion, you need to define a custom mapping(as far as I know. Draw a new graph, and I will attempt to find a mathematical function that works.)

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this as well? Sorry to necrobump but I'm interested in seeing if it's possible

Comment: For anyone trying to leverage a version of this today, you'll actually want to run `Math.log` on the entered and min/max values separately before operating, something like this:
`const mx = (Math.log(enteredValue) - Math.log(minEntry)) / (Math.log(maxEntry) - Math.log(minEntry))`